# How do I interpret a differential of a function with more than one argument (written i general form)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can someone help tell me how I am supposed to understand the last expression in the section below? For example, is $f_1$ simply the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t $x_1$ or does the expression imply something more? Maybe this question is trivial, but I think it's hard do follow when only the general form of a function is used.

"Consider the contour
$$
f\left(x_1, x_2\right)=c \text{ [eq.1]}
$$

From the Implicit Function Theorem we have that, given $f_2 \neq 0$, we can solve eq.1
for $x_2$ as a function of $x_1, x_2\left(x_1\right)$, and so substituting into eq.1 and differentiating with respect to $x_1$ gives

$$
\frac{d f\left(x_1, x_2\left(x_1\right)\right)}{d x_1}=f_1+f_2 \frac{d x_2}{d x_1}=0
$$"

Comment: Yes. A total derivative expressed in partial derivatives. This is also called implicit differentiation, as it gives $\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}$ without having the equation for the curve.

Comment: Thanks. So $f_2 \frac{d x_2}{d x_1}$ is derived using the chain rule, where $f_2$ is the outer derivative and $\frac{d x_2}{d x_1}$ is the inner derivative (w.r.t $x_1$)?

Comment: Yes. In a more generalistic view, what you have is a composition $f\circ \phi$ with $\phi(x_1)=(x_1,x_2(x_1))$, so that from the chain rule you get a product of row and column vectors as outer and inner derivative.